# How to find a specific child element with Protractor

Tags: css-selectors, protractor

I have a lot of difficult to find one element inside other.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POPum.png)

Inside this, I need to compare if one of them, has an element with a specific text that I need, and click on it.

I already tried to use:

```
element.all(locator).filter(filterFn)
```

*ERROR: - Failed: Index out of bound. Trying to access element at index: 0*, but there are only 0 elements that match locator By(css selector, #main > app-playbook-list-page > app-playbook-grid > div.d-flex.flex-row.flex-wrap)

```
element(locator).$(selector)
```

- create a variable to save the all elements

Do someone have any idea to solve this?

Comment: Error describes that by this specific locator you did not find `any` elements.

Comment: Please show your code and HTML code (your given screenshot can't tell us what text you expect to find in side which element)

Comment: I solved this problem with a easy solution: element(by.cssContainingText('div', 'text')); Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$$('div.d-flex.flex-row.flex-wrap>div.flex-column');
```

Try the locator to get the array of elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out this may help you

```
element.all(by.locator(element)).filter(function(el,index){
                return el.isDisplayed();
            }).first().click();
```